# truncate linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, devices, truncate

firstly sorry for my English.

I want to truncate kernel options like Bluetooth, mouse, keyboard etc.. except for my use.

but how can I know that kernel options related to devices that I want to remove?

I've been that work with "make menuconfig".

I've been read the description of kernel options and uncheck the options.

Does any summary exist on the website? or any way that can work?

please tell me. Thank you

Comment: If you run `lspci -k` you'll get a list of your PCI devices and the drivers for them.  You can use that as a _starting point_ hardware wise. You'll still need things unrelated to hardware (e.g., filesystems, etc.)

Comment: Compile everything you can as modules instead of building the drivers into the kernel. You can get a list of the modules in use on the running system with `lsmod`. The rest of the modules you can delete, if you are tight on space.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thank you for your comment. I really understand well what you saying but I have a question one more. If I know modules that I don't need first, and then how can I know kernel options related to the modules? Just grid search in GUI of "make menuconfig"?